# lagrange theorem question True/false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is  there exist positive integers $n$ and $m$ with $n < m < n!$ such that $S_n $ has a cyclic subgroup of order $m$ ?

My attempts  : i thinks  No, because  by lagrange theorem   that is  $m \nmid n$ because   $m > n$

Is it coorect ?

Comment: Not as directly as you wrote it since Lagrange's theorem says that if there is a subgroup of order $\;m\;$ in $\;S_n\;$ then it must be that $\;m\,\mid\,n!\left(=|S_n|\right)\;$ , which could be true.

Comment: @DonAntonio..but  $ n! \nmid  n$ ???

Comment: Yes, I know...and what does that have anything to do with Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: i mean    so  there  is no  cyclic subgoup of order  m

Comment: Again, where dod you deduce that from?! And read my answer...

Comment: I think you're confusing $\;n\;$ with the order of $\;S_n\;$ , which is $\;n!\;$ . Two very different things!

Comment: thanks  u  @DonAntonio..got  its

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\;12<14<12!\;$ . The subgroup $\;\langle (1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6\,7)(8\,9)\rangle\le S_{12}\;$ is cyclic and has order $\;14\;$